# Retrieve model data from a controller using Next.js and Sequelize

Tags: javascript, next.js, sequelize.js

I'm working on a project where my Vue.js is my frontend and my Next.js is my backend. Everything seems to go well, but I don't know how to get my model data back to my controller...

More info :

- I used Sequelize to create my models, migrations and seeders.
- My db is on PostgreSQL

Here is my controller (recetteController.js) where I call findAllRecette() :

```
// import { Recette } from '../../models/recette';
const { Recette } = require('../../models/recette');
// const Recette = require('../../models/recette');

console.log(Recette);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    try {
        const recettes = await Recette.getAllRecette(); 
        res.status(200).json(recettes);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erreur lors de la récupération des recettes' });
    }
}
```

Here is my model (recette) where is my function getAllRecette() :

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Recette extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Recette.belongsTo(models.Difficulte, { foreignKey: 'id_difficulte', as: 'difficulte' });
      Recette.belongsTo(models.Categorie, { foreignKey: 'id_categorie', as: 'categorie' });
    }
  
    // Récupère toutes les recettes
    static async getAllRecette() {
      console.log("CONGRATS");
      const recettes = await this.findAll();
      return recettes;
    }
  }

  Recette.init({
    nom: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    portion: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    temps: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    id_difficulte: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    id_categorie: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    image: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Recette',
  });

  return Recette;
};
```

I have never done this before except for Laravel and maybe I am doing this wrong ... (MVC)

The problem is that the console.log(Recette) gives me a *'undefined'* or *'[Function (anonymous)]'* depending on how I import **Recette**

I have also tried to call findAll() directly in my controller but that did not change the fact that my controller doesn't found my model.

please i spent too much time fixing this ! Thank you !

Comment: Next doesn't use MVC, currently the problem is with modules and Sequelize. Where did you get boilerplate code for a model? You shouldn't import directly a model that's defined this way, that there's (sequelize, DataTypes) => function means that Sequelize that should import it and inject its instance, like shown in the docs, https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/moved/models-definition/ .   Don't use CJS and require() if you can use ES modules, there will be problems if you try to use them together, there was a good reason why you had "undefined"

Comment: Ho right ! I used Vue.js as the back & frontend, then switch to split the project to Next.js and Vue.js. I just copied the migrates, seeders and models files. I guess it was not the best idea. But everything works perfecly now ! Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how : use import {} instead of require() and add a connection to the db in a js file like so :

```
//database.js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('db_name', 'user', 'password', {
  host: 'host_name',
  dialect: 'dialect', //ex:postgres
  logging: console.log, //activate sequelize log 
});

(async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Database connection successfully established.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to the database :', error);
  }
})();

export default sequelize;
```

Then use this file in your models files like so : (**import sequelize from 'database';**)

```
//model.js
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from 'database';

class MyClass extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
   
  }

}

export default (sequelize) => {
  Recette.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    //... 
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'MyClass',
  });

  return MyClass;
};

export { MyClass };
```

Then the controller should look like that :

```
import {MyClass} from '../models/myClass';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    const datas = await MyClass.findAll(); 
    res.status(200).json(datas);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error while fetching datas' });
  }
};
```